# Proof: $\phi$ is monotonly decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi : [0,+\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuousand two times differentiable function, such that $\phi'(0)=0$ and $\phi''(t) \leq -3\phi'(t)$.

Proof that $\phi$ is monotonly decreasing.

My idea was to show that the first derivative is $\leq 0 $. But I‘m having a hard time to show that.

Answer (score 2):

$$\Longleftrightarrow \phi''(x)e^{3x}+3\phi'(x)e^{3x} \le 0\Longleftrightarrow \left(\phi'(x)e^{3x}\right)' \le 0$$
We deduce that $\phi'(x)e^{3x}$ is decreasing, then for $x \in [0, +\infty[$ :
$$\phi'(x)e^{3x}\le \phi'(0)e^{0} = 0 \implies \phi'(x) \le 0$$
Q.E.D

Answer (score 0):

$\phi$ is strictly decreasing whenever it is positive. If there were an $x$ such that $\phi'(x) > 0$, then we would also have $\phi'(y) > \phi'(x)> 0$ for all $y < x$, which would violate $\phi'(0) = 0$.